# Making An HTTP PUT through BrightScript to AWS S3 Bucket with pre-signed url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, brightscript

I've set up an AWS api which obtainins a pre-signed URL for uploading to an AWS S3 bucket.

The pre-signed url has a format like

https://s3.amazonaws.com/mahbukkit/background4.png?AWSAccessKeyId=someaccesskeyQ&Expires=1513287500&x-amz-security-token=somereallylongtokenvalue

where backgournd4.png would be the file I'm uploading.

I can successfully use this URL through Postman By:

1. configuring it as a PUT call,
2. setting the body to Binary so I can select the file,
3. setting the header to Content-Type: image/png

HOWEVER, I'm trying to make this call using BrightScript running on a BrightSign player.  I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to be using the roURTransfer object and PutFromFile function described in this doucmentation:

http://docs.brightsign.biz/display/DOC/roUrlTransfer

Unfortunately, I can't find any good working examples showing how to do this.

Could anyone who has experience with BrightScript help me out?  I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

you are on the right track.

i would do

```
sub main()

tr = createObject("roUrlTransfer")
headers = {}
headers.addreplace("Content-Type","image/png")

tr.AddHeaders(headers)
info = {}
info.method = "PUT"
info.request_body_file = <fileName>

if tr.AsyncMethod(info)
    print "File put Started"
else
    print "File put did not start"
end if 
delay(100000) 
end  sub()
```

note i have used two different methods to populate the two associative arrays. you need to use the addreplace method (rather then the shortcut of .) when the key contains special characters like '-'

this script should work , though i don't have a unit on hand to do a syntax check. 
also you should set up a message port etc and Listen to the event that is generated to confirm if the put was successful and/or what the response code is. 
note when you read responses from url events. if the response code from the server is anything other then 200 the BrightSign will trash the response body and you can not read it. This is not helpful as services like dropbox like to do a 400 response with more info on what was wrong (bad API key etc) in the body. so in that case you are left in the dark doing trial and error to figure out what was wrong.

good luck, sorry i didn't see this question sooner.